How to use Next's Placeholder Blur when handling MDX
I am quite new to code (and definitely don't know much).
I am building my design portfolio and I want that images load with Next Image's placeholder blur, the problem is that it's throwing me this error:
Error: Image with src "/projects/ellingsen/Imagen%201.webp" has "placeholder='blur'" property but is missing the "blurDataURL" property. Possible solutions: - Add a "blurDataURL" property, the contents should be a small Data URL to represent the image - Change the "src" property to a static import with one of the supported file types: jpeg,png,webp,avif (animated images not supported) - Remove the "placeholder" property, effectively no blur effect Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/placeholder-blur-data-url
Although these are static (are in my public folder), it won't even recognize the width and height of them. I have been trying to fix it myself, but can't seem to find and answer.
My mdx.jsx looks like this:
enter image description here
Thanks in advance.
I have tried to set up a getBase64 function but I ended up with a "module not found: can't resolve "child_process"

[ensure that your image format is  .jpg, .png, .webp, or .avif. If it is not,you'll have to add a base64 blurDataURL for your image][1]

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#placeholder
